# Rename field in database and reinstall app

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I am learning Android and now i have lesson about the database - PetTracker.

http://androidsvnex.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/androidsvnex/PetListTracker/src/kr/co/sqlite/persistent/pet/PetDatabase.java

I use Eclipse + my phone for testing.

I would like rename field in this app and this working ok, but if i run application after changes then i have error - field not exist, but if i unninstall app on my phone and again run app then this working ok.

So how can i make if i run as application then database should be also updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the [onUpgrade](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29) Method in the SQLiteOpenHelper. You should code something like this.

```
public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion,int newVersion){
  String update = ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD COLUMN <column_name> <column_type>;
  db.execSQL(update);
}
```

[Alter](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) Table gives you very limited options in performing an update to the database tables. If you want to copy your data into a completely new structure, you should think about creating temporary tables where you can copy data, create the new schema and then copy your data from the temporary tables to the new table, in this upgrade method.

Make sure you have your DB Version numbers correct while creating the DBHelper.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement [onUpgrade()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)) and write yours update tables here. 
Also you need to increment your database version passing a new version in [SqliteOpenHelper contructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int)).